# width=100% in div isnt't making it responsive

Tags: html

Hey so I was working on making my subscribers area responsive. Have created a div container for the whole area. But setting width=100% isn't making the area responsive.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
<div style= "width:100%; height:auto; border-radius:4px; background-color:#36424d; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; padding-top:40px; padding-bottom:40px; padding-left:40px; padding-right:40px;">
    <h2 style="color:#ffffff;"><b><center>Get actionable influencer marketing advice. Delivered weekly.</center></b></h2>
    <h3 style="color:#ffffff"><center>Join 6308 good looking people who get our latest content first.</center></h3>     
  <br/>
    <div style= "background-color:#dee5e5; border-radius:3px; padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px">
    <input type="email" name="EMAIL" placeholder="Your business/personal email address" required />
    </div>  

    <div style="text-align: center;">
    <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you mean by "responsive"? It's responsive (adaptive) to me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove width OR to add inner div and give padding there

```html
<div style= "width:100%; height:auto; border-radius:4px; background-color:#36424d; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; padding-top:40px; padding-bottom:40px;">
<div style=" padding-left:40px; padding-right:40px;">
    <h2 style="color:#ffffff;"><b><center>Get actionable influencer marketing advice. Delivered weekly.</center></b></h2>
    <h3 style="color:#ffffff"><center>Join 6308 good looking people who get our latest content first.</center></h3>     
  <br/>
    <div style= "background-color:#dee5e5; border-radius:3px; padding-left:0px; padding-right:0px">
    <input type="email" name="EMAIL" placeholder="Your business/personal email address" required style="width:100%;height:32px;border-radius:3px;" />
    </div>  

    <div style="text-align: center;">
    <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" style="margin:5px auto; border-radius:3px;" />
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, this isn't helping with the desktop browsers. Neither with Chrome, not Firefox. The same problem still persists.

Comment: @NiranjanSingh check now I have changed css in subscriber div

Comment: Hey, how would adding changes in the child div make any changes in the parent div? This didn't work

Comment: so I just found out. The design is responsive for browser window width <990px, but losses it responsiveness beyond it. Any idea?

Comment: Hey, so setting width=100vw did the job. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Setting width=100vw did the job for me. You can set it to any other number depending upon your need.

```
<div style= "width:96vw; height:auto; border-radius:4px; background-color:#36424d; 
             padding-top:40px; padding-bottom:40px; 
             padding-left:40px; padding-right:80px;">
```

Comment: Looks the same to me.